# How to get predecessor id from task predecessor string?

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language, mpxj

I'm working on MPXJ library. I want to get predecessors id from below string. It's complex for me. Please help me get all predecessors id. Thanks.

Task predecessor string:

```
Task Predecessors:[[Relation [Task id=12 uniqueID=145 name=Alibaba1] -> [Task id=10 uniqueID=143 name=Alibaba2]],
[Relation [Task id=12 uniqueID=145 name=Alibaba3] -> [Task id=11 uniqueID=144 name=Alibaba4]], [Relation [Task id=12 uniqueID=145 name=Alibaba5] -> [Task id=9 uniqueID=142 name=Alibaba6]]]
```

I need get the predecessors id: `10`, `11`, `9`

Pattern:

```
[Task id=12 uniqueID=145 name=Alibaba1] -> [Task id=10 uniqueID=143 name=Alibaba2]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To grab those **ID**'s you need to look for the Task id after `->` You can try the following using [Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"->\s*\[Task\s*id=(\d+)");

foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

[**Working Demo**](http://ideone.com/pNzP5D)

**Explanation**:

```
->          # '->'
\s*         # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
\[          # '['
 Task       # 'Task'
 \s*        # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
 id=        # 'id='
  (         # group and capture to \1:
   \d+      #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  )         # end of \1
```

Answer (score 3):

**No need for capture groups. See full [C# online demo](http://ideone.com/VZb7Bb)**

My original answer used capture groups. But we don't need them.

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=-> \[Task id=)\d+
```

See the output of at the very bottom of this [C# online demo](http://ideone.com/VZb7Bb):

```
10
11
9
```

- The `(?<=-> \[Task id=)` lookbehind ensures that we are preceded by the section from the arrow to the equal sign
- `\d+` matches the id

This C# code adds all the codes to `resultList`:

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=-> \[Task id=)\d+");
Match matchResult = myRegex.Match(s1);
while (matchResult.Success) {
resultList.Add(matchResult.Value);
Console.WriteLine(matchResult.Value);
matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

**Original Version with Capture Groups**

To give you a second option, here is my [original demo](http://ideone.com/mItbC1) using a capture group.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)